# Did anybody steal my coins?

Tags: support, fun, unicoins, unicorns

I let my money hidden under some rocks near that path that goes through the green hills, close to the rainbow.

Here you have a picture of the exact location.

[image]

Please if somebody found some of my coins, or saw who could took them, please let me know.

I can offer a juicy bounty: I have bacon, unicorns, and unicorn bacon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unicorn bacon??? that is blasphemous!

Comment: @bluefeet aw, well, i mean...you know...bacon cooked by a unicorn...

Comment: You better not be murdering unicorns for their yummy goodness!